# Debugging slow postgres server connect

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

We have recently migrated to postgres 9.4 from mysql and were getting some really poor performance. All cpu cores just end up on 100% whenever our celery cluster starts working. Coming from MySQL before this, the cpus never really went more than ~20%.

I'm not sure where to start but I did this as a quick test. This may not matter too much but I thought it would be a test for connections speed. So I atleast know i am loosing a lot of time just from the connect before I even get into query performance.

```
# Postgres
$ time for i in `seq 1 100`; do sudo -u postgres psql db -c "select 1" > /dev/null; done

real    0m5.498s
user    0m3.317s
sys     0m0.660s

# MySQL
$ time for i in `seq 1 100`; do mysql -uroot -ppass db -e 'select 1;' > /dev/null; done

real    0m0.664s
user    0m0.153s
sys     0m0.310s
```

Postgres config looks like this

```
data_directory = '/data/pg_data'
hba_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf'
ident_file = '/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_ident.conf'
external_pid_file = '/var/run/postgresql/9.4-main.pid'

listen_addresses = '192.168.172.34, localhost'
port = 5432
max_connections = 200
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql'
ssl = true
ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'
ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'

shared_buffers = 1GB
work_mem = 5242kB
maintenance_work_mem = 256MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix

wal_buffers = 16MB                      # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
checkpoint_segments = 32                # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7      # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0

effective_cache_size = 3GB
default_statistics_target = 100

log_line_prefix = '%t [%p-%l] %q%u@%d '
log_timezone = 'UTC'
stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/9.4-main.pg_stat_tmp'

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#intervalstyle = 'postgres'
timezone = 'UTC'
#timezone_abbreviations = 'Default'
#extra_float_digits = 0
#client_encoding = sql_ascii

lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'

default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

Comment: Your "test" only measures the time for {connection buildup+authorisation+empty query+empty result+connection breakdown} Use real actual queries to obtain real performance measurements. set `log_min_duration_statement`  to detect slow queries, and check their query plans http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-logging.html

Comment: I understand that but its quite clear the connection/auth/disconnect is taking a lot longer than I think it should. Or maybe this is normal with postgres?

Comment: What sort of connect/disconnect rate were you doing before? If you can't use an in-app connection pool, you might want to put PgBouncer in front of PostgreSQL to do server-side connection pooling. High connect/disconnect rates won't perform wonderfully, and I wouldn't be too surprised if MySQL was faster at that. It usually is at doing lots of very small, simple, lightweight operations. Note, though, that you're testing *`psql` start time* not just server connection time.

Comment: Thanks ill look into it.

Comment: Oh, you might also simply be using *too many connections*. Try limiting it to 20 or so. Yes, really. Unless you have some kind of 64-core monster server, you will get better results with fewer connections.

Comment: Thanks for two very helpful answers. I'll look into connection pooling :)

Comment: To see the difference, compare: https://gist.github.com/ringerc/7642350fee9f729d1466 . 5 seconds is ridiculous. It doesn't help that for some reason you're measuring `sudo` time ... each iteration, all 100 times.  That's a *bad plan*. I'm sure you're measuring the wrong thing here, and your real issue lies elsewhere. If I get rid of sudo, that loop takes 0.1 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Yes your example is much better. Makes a lot of sense. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL backends are new processes. Even though they're fork()ed from the postmaster, so they avoid a lot of startup overhead, they're not free.

Nonetheless, there's so much wrong with this comparison that you're comparing apples to oil tankers.

- You're using `sudo` for each iteration. *Why?*. That's totally unrelated to what you're doing, and massively outweighs the costs of everything else. Without that the same test takes 0.1 seconds on my laptop.
- You're comparing *command-line client startup times* as well as connect/disconnect times. That's unlikely to mean anything relevant for your application.
- You're doing 100 connections serially, not in parallel. Behaviour will be quite different. It's unlikely that your app does just one thing at a time.
- Any sensible application pools connections anyway, and avoids connection start/shutdown overheads. If yours doesn't and can't easily be fixed to, put PgBouncer between the app and the PostgreSQL server as a connection pooling proxy.

If you're having performance issues you need to *identify what they are* before concocting unrelated benchmarks.

You will find the `log_min_duration_statement` setting useful, as is `log_lock_waits`. Also perhaps the `auto_explain` module, and the `pg_stat_statements` module.

For more system level bottleneck finding work use `top`, `vmstat`, `iostat`, `iotop`, and if you really have to get into the guts, `perf`.

Also, more connections does not mean better. The single biggest performance improvement I make to most people's systems is shrinking their connection pools. Got an 8-core server with decently fast storage? Then going from 50 to 100 connections will probably just slow it down, and going from 100 to 500 will grind it to a crawl.

Finally, if you actually *did* have slow connect times, the main things to look into would be too many active connections, oversaturated I/O, memory exhaustion causing swapping, and reverse lookups enabled with DNS problems.

Answer (score 0):

That result is just a little more what i would expect. PostgreSQL simply does a *lot* more work when a session is established. Not as much as it takes a cruise ship longer to start than a motorboat, but you should get the idea.

Normally, apps or DB-drivers should - and will - reuse DB-sessions.

If your application does not, most probably somebody (mis?)configured it that way. Which then would be the easiest fix.

If your app can't reuse sessions, or you can't configure the app because you are "just" the DB-Admin: Look for Pgpool which will do that.